# 'Invalid CORS request' returned by microservice after passing Zuul gateway

Tags: spring-boot, cors, netflix-zuul

I have a Spring Boot service behind a Zuul gateway, deployed on a remote server. I am accessing these through an Ionic app from my local machine. I've setup a corsFilter in my Zuul application as follows:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("*");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
```

The request is accepted by Zuul and passed on to the microservice (I can see it in the microservice logs) however the microservice rejects the request and returns a 403 error 'Invalid CORS request'.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do the logs of the microservice say? If you're using anything external there, what does its documentation say about which CORS headers/parameters it will take or demands?

Comment: The microservice logs don't say anything, just a printout in the filter that I added. It is a mixed Java / Kotlin service, could that have an impact?

Comment: @AdamK did you got any solution, I am also facing same problem and I am having same project structure.

Comment: @Pallavi No sorry I wasn't able to solve the problem. I'm no longer working on the project so I haven't looked since. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to use the spring cors filter.

```java
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
  final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new 
  UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
  final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
  config.setAllowCredentials(true);
  config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
  config.addExposedHeader("Content-Type");
  config.addExposedHeader("Authorization");
  config.addExposedHeader("Accept");
  config.addExposedHeader("Origin");
  config.addAllowedHeader("*");
  config.addAllowedMethod("*");
  source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
  return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

Comment: Hi pan, I'm afraid this didn't work either. Same problem, I can see it's getting to the service but is being rejected there and returning 403 'Invalid CORS request'.